# How do I write my name with turtles in python?

Tags: python

I have started, but don't know how to continue. I'm a beginner, so try to use simple terms. I want to write "Noah" with `turtle` library.

My code so far:

```
import turtle

t=turtle.Turtle()

t.penup
t.speed(3)
t.color("blue")
t.penup
t.begin_fill()

t.goto(1,1)
t.right(280)
t.forward(90)
```

Comment: I'm not clear what your question is.  You seem to understand some basics for moving the turtle around.  Are you asking for the exact numbers to use?  The only issue I see with your current code is the penup lines -- to invoke the method, add empty parens, like `t.penup()`.

Comment: You might want to put the turtle's pen down, if you want to see it draw

Comment: @DaveCosta Thank you i will try. Let's see what happens. Will edit my progress

Comment: Can you be more specific? Please see [ask], [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 1):

Using your code as a base, here's an "N":

```
import turtle

t=turtle.Turtle()

t.penup
t.speed(3)
t.color("blue")
t.penup
t.begin_fill()

t.goto(1,1)
t.right(270)
t.forward(90)
t.right(160)
t.forward(95)
t.left(160)
t.forward(90)
t.penup()
t.goto(80,80)
t.pendown()

turtle.done()
```

I've added `turtle.done()` at the end so the window doesn't immediately close.

`t.penup` means you're "lifting the pen off the paper", with `pendown()` meaning the opposite.

Comment: Thank you sir. Do you know the drift or tilt command that makes it easier to make a circle?

Comment: The circle function is just `circle()`, so in your case it's `t.circle(r)` with `r` as the radius

Comment: The circle doesn't start where I want it to start. And t-goto doesn't work. Sorry if I sound stupid.

Comment: Lift the pen with `pendown()`, then `goto()` somewhere, then put the pen back down, and then draw the circle

Comment: So something like this.                        t.penup()
t.goto(45,50)
t.pendown()
t.circle(20)

Comment: Yes. By the way, if you like my original answer please click the checkmark button to mark it as solved